# How do I get my music back on Banshee?

Tags: banshee

My Banshee Media Player on my laptop deleted all my songs. I pressed "Remove from Library" on one song and it deleted all my songs. How do I get them back? I need help ASAP.

Comment: Is this a trick question? Please tells us what you have tried and what did not work. The songs removed from the library are only links to the music files on the hard disk. The song files are still in the music folder or whatever folder you downloaded them into. You repeat what you first did to get Banshee playing those files. If you have tried this and it did not work, then you must tell us.

Answer (score 4):

As @grahammechanical said in the comment above, all of your music should still be on your computer -- probably in your ~/Music folder.  From within Banshee, go to `Tools > Rescan Music Library` and Banshee should automatically re-import all of the songs.  If that doesn't work, you can re-import manually by going to `Media > Import Media`, and choose to import your entire Music folder.

But removing all of your songs when you try to remove one is a very weird issue.  If you can reproduce the problem, I'm sure the Banshee developers would appreciate it if you report it here: http://banshee.fm/contribute/file-bugs/

Before you try to test this out (and in general, if you're worried about problems with your music library) you might want to make a backup copy of your database.  The following command will create a copy of your Banshee database in the same folder as the normal database:

```
cp ~/.config/banshee-1/banshee.db ~/.config/banshee-1/banshee.db.backup
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much! It actually worked! I would've never figured out how to do that! Thanks again!